# How should I respond to a review request after a review was declined?

Tags: peer-review

I reviewed a manuscript for a journal from a well-known publisher.

I received

> A gentle reminder that we sent you an invitation on ... to review the revised version of the following paper

I responded with

> Please allow 18 days.  My partner just had emergency surgery.

The journal said

> We are truly sorry that we would cancel the revised invitation.

Then 93 minutes later, the same editor at the same journal sent me

> We kindly invite you to review this paper and evaluate its suitability for
> publication

for a different paper.

What is the professional way to respond?

Comment: Their first response doesn't sound like a native English speaker. Is there a communication problem?

Comment: Journals in my field ask for a reply on a web interface. There is always the option to decline without reason or with a standard "too busy" reason. Is that not the case in your field? I believe you are dealing with a semi-automated process here and you shouldn't treat it as a conversation with the editor.

Comment: It is possible that the journal uses an automated review management system and the request was sent out automatically rather than by the editor.

Answer (score 36):

If you can assume, perhaps over generously, that this was an inadvertent mistake, then you can just say "For personal/professional reasons, I can't accept any requests until Oct 1 (or whenever)".

People make mistakes.

---

Best wishes to your partner.

Answer (score 4):

I'd respond just like I would for any paper I'm not in a situation to review --  "I'm sorry, but I'm not available to review this manuscript at this time." There's no reason to call attention to the editor's faux pas.